# What is the RubyGems equivalent for --with-ruby-include?

Tags: rubygems, rake

How would I code the following in a rake file (RubyGems.org)?

```
gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-head
```

What I currently have looks like this:

```
gem "ruby-debug19", "~> 0.11.6"
```

But I now want to update it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before running 
bundler install

you need to configure bundler with:

```
bundle config build.ruby-debug19 --with-ruby-include=/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-head
```

good luck